# Using Editable Plugin

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am a novice at implementing jQuery add ons. I'd like to use editable on my site:

http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html

I am using 2 jQuery add ons on my site already... but the packages had all files I need. So I have a scripts folder, with jquery-1.4.1... And then a folder for each 'plugin', such as 'plupload', and in there I have a whole lot of .js files and a few folders. This was a folder downloaded from the authors site.

With 'editable', they only provide a single .js file. What do I do with it (Where should I copy it on my site structure), and how do I 'include' it in my project, so that I can make use of the code they provide?

My html code looks like this:

```
<div id="editable"> Click Me </div>
```

and I have my function at the bottom of as ascx file:

```
    .....        
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#gallery a').lightBox({
                    imageBtnClose: '/lightbox/images/lightbox-btn-close.gif'
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('div.editable').editable();
            });
        </script>

</asp:Content>
```

And I have this at the top of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.editable-1.3.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting the .js file in your scripts folder? Then add this tag to your `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.editable-1.3.3.js"></script>
```

Where the src points to your file.

Once that is done you should just use this (or any other settings you want) within another `<script>` tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.editable').editable();
});
```

Where `div.editable` is the div you want to be editable.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this - but failed so far. My html looks like this: <div id="div.editable">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
                                </div> Can you spy a problem?

Comment: I have also tried this, but nothing happens when I click: <div id="editable">
                                    Click Me
                                </div>

Answer (score 1):

With most one file plugins, you'll only have to do it like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery.Editable.js"></script>
</head>
```